# DWT and FFT on a very low frequency signals

Tags: discrete-signals, machine-learning, eeg, feature-extraction

I am trying to extract features from a very low frequency signal of $0.1$ HZ and less than $100$ samples. Is it advisable to use FFT and DWT on this signal?

Comment: well, what's your sampling rate? It makes a lot of a difference whether your sampling rate is 0.2 Hz or 100 MHz.

Comment: There is only one sample per every 10 seconds. It’s 0.1 Hz. And the number of samples in the signal are 60 which comprises of a 10minute data.

Comment: so, then 0.1 is not the *signal frequency*, but the sampling rate? In that case, the question goes the other way around: what are frequencies of the signals you're interested in? In DSP, neither your signal frequency nor the sampling rate alone are useful to know – it's how they are related.

Comment: I am not looking at a particular frequency. It was downsampled from 256Hz. I am trying to extract features from the current signal to build a classifier. There were some activity at the frequency components less than 0.02Hz when I tried applying FFT. So, I was wondering if it is reasonable to apply DWT on this kind of low frequency signals to extract statistical features.

Comment: what is a "feature" to you? You can apply anything, again, the DSP doesn't care about your sampling rates at all. whether or not that yields a sensible result depends on how your signal relates to the sampling rate, and you've not clarified that.